# How to redirect a page based on referring/current URLs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

So this is what I have - I want to use an or, but not 100% on it.

```
if(document.location.href.indexOf('test/test/test1') > -1) { 
    document.location.href = 'http://www.test.com/thank-you';
}
if(document.location.href.indexOf('test/test/test9') > -1) { 
    document.location.href = 'http://www.test.com/thank-you';
}
```

Would it be:

```
if(document.location.href.indexOf('test/test/test1' || 'test/test/test9') > -1) { 
    document.location.href = 'http://www.test.com/thank-you';
}
```

Comment: RegEx is out - the real URLs are too different (sorry). Variables are nice, but will be too much in the long run.  Looks like I repeat as stated below.  I just can't believe there isn't way around having to say document.location.href.indexof () twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
if(document.location.href.indexOf('test/test/test1') > -1
  || document.location.href.indexOf('test/test/test9') > -1) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the entire expression:

if(document.location.href.indexOf('test/test/test1'> -1 || document.location.href.indexOf('test/test/test1' > -1) { 
.....

Answer (score 0):

It might be shorter and easier to use a Regex:

```
var regex = /test\/test\/(test1|test9)/
if (regex.test(document.location.href)) { 
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using variables:

```
var found1 = document.location.href.indexOf('test/test/test1') > -1;
var found9 = document.location.href.indexOf('test/test/test9') > -1;

if(found1 || found9) {
    document.location.href = 'http://www.test.com/thank-you';
}
```

You can also use a regular expression if the 1 or 9 in the url may be something else, like a number:

```
var found = document.location.href.match(/\/test\/test\/test\d$/); // returns an array of matches.

if(found) {
    document.location.href = 'http://www.test.com/thank-you';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function:

```
// This function accepts an array as a parameter
function findInURL(arr)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if(document.location.href.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

And use it like:

```
if(findInURL(['test/test/test1', 'test/test/test9', 'test/test/foo']))
    document.location.href = 'http://www.test.com/thank-you';
```